# How to regroup tuples in list of list of tuples by checking the one of the tuple values?

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

Given the input list of list of tuples:

```
input_lol = [ [('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], 
              [('yy', 'AB'), ('..', 'Punct'), ('foo', 'ZZ')], 
              [('y', 'AB')] 
            ]
```

The desired output is to regroup the inner list of tuples such that the tuples that contains `'Punct'` in the second element of the tuples are singled out and any tuples before the `'Punct'` containing tuple is grouped into the previous list.

E.g. desired output:

```
desired_lolol = [ [[('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], [('yy', 'AB')]], 
                 ('..', 'Punct'), 
                [[('foo', 'ZZ')], [('y', 'AB')]] 
              ]
```

Another example:

```
input_lol = [ [('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], 
              [('yy', 'AB'), ('..', 'Punct'), ('foo', 'ZZ')], 
              [('y', 'AB')], 
              [('ybar', 'CC')],
              [('z', 'NJ'), ('!', 'Punct')],
              [('pals', 'AJB')], 
            ]

desired_lolol = [ [[('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], [('yy', 'AB')]], 
                  ('..', 'Punct'), 
                  [[('foo', 'ZZ')], [('y', 'AB')]], [('ybar', 'CC')], [('z', 'NJ')],
                  ('!', 'Punct'),
                  [('pals', 'AJB')], 
              ]
```

Another example:

```
input_lol = [ [('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], 
              [('yy', 'AB'), ('..', 'Punct'), ('bar', 'YY'), ('..', 'Punct'), ('foo', 'ZZ')], 
              [('y', 'AB')], 
              [('ybar', 'CC')],
              [('z', 'NJ'), ('!', 'Punct')],
              [('pals', 'AJB')], 
            ]

desired_lolol = [ [[('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], [('yy', 'AB')]], 
                  ('..', 'Punct'), 
                  [('bar', 'YY')], 
                  ('..', 'Punct'), 
                  [[('foo', 'ZZ')], [('y', 'AB')]], [('ybar', 'CC')], [('z', 'NJ')],
                  ('!', 'Punct'),
                  [('pals', 'AJB')], 
              ]
```

I've tried:

```
desired_lolol = []
output_inner_lol = []

for inner_list_of_tuple in input_lol:
    if any(tag == 'Punct' for s, tag in inner_list_of_tuple):
        pending = []
        for s, tag in inner_list_of_tuple:
            if tag == 'Punct':
                desired_lolol.append(pending)
                desired_lolol.append((s,tag))
                pending = []
            else:
                pending.append((s,tag))
        if pending:
            desired_lolol.append((s,tag))
    else:
        desired_lolol.append(inner_list_of_tuple)
```

and got this:

```
[[('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')],
 [('yy', 'AB')],
 ('..', 'Punct'),
 ('foo', 'ZZ'),
 [('y', 'AB')]]
```

But the `[('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')]` and `[('yy', 'AB')]` isn't group into one list. So I had to do some post-processing:

```
desired_lolol = []
output_inner_lol = []

for inner_list_of_tuple in input_lol:
    if any(tag == 'Punct' for s, tag in inner_list_of_tuple):
        pending = []
        for s, tag in inner_list_of_tuple:
            if tag == 'Punct':
                desired_lolol.append(pending)
                desired_lolol.append((s,tag))
                pending = []
            else:
                pending.append((s,tag))
        if pending:
            desired_lolol.append((s,tag))
    else:
        desired_lolol.append(inner_list_of_tuple)

really_desired_lolol = []
pending = []
for x in desired_lolol:
    if type(x) == tuple and x[1] == 'Punct':
        really_desired_lolol.append(pending)
        really_desired_lolol.append(x)
        pending = []
    else:
        pending += x

if pending:
    really_desired_lolol.append(pending)
```

**Is there a simpler way to get the `desired_lolol`?**

Comment: Can you say anything about the nature of the input, like the Punct tuples will only occur once in the sublist that contains them>?

Comment: Punct tuples will occur multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive solution for data of arbitrary depth:

```
def get_punc(current):
    updated_data = [get_punc(i) if any(isinstance(c, list) for c in i) else i for i in current]
    new_data = iter(updated_data)
    final_data = []
    while True:
        result = next(new_data, None)
        if not result:
            return final_data

        if any(a == 'Punct' for _,a  in result):
            the_index = [i for i, a in enumerate(result) if a[1] == 'Punct'][0]
            if the_index > 0:
                final_data[-1].append(result[:the_index])
            final_data.append(result[the_index])
            if the_index < len(result)-1:
                final_data.append([result[the_index+1:]])
        else:

            if final_data and isinstance(final_data[-1], list):
                final_data[-1].append(result)
            else :
                if not final_data or not isinstance(final_data[-1], tuple):
                    final_data.append([result])  
                else: 
                    final_data.append([result])
```

Output:

```
[[[('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], [('yy', 'AB')]], ('..', 'Punct'), [[('foo', 'ZZ')], [('y', 'AB')]]]
--------------------
[[[('x', 'AA'), ('y', 'AB')], [('yy', 'AB')]], ('..', 'Punct'), [[('foo', 'ZZ')], [('y', 'AB')], [('ybar', 'CC')], [('z', 'NJ')]], ('..', 'Punct'), [('pals', 'AJB')]]
--------------------
```

Comment: Now it looks better but it's not as simple as I thought.

Comment: Wait a minute! the most inner if else at the has no difference.

Comment: @alvas The main task is that the structure of the original input needs to be maintained, with the exception of the punctuation tuples. Therefore, the code has to account for the fact that non-punctuation tuples need to be inserted properly in the correct place, hence the slightly longer solution.